# Is there any advantage to rebooting my computer after handling sensitive information?

Tags: memory, key

A habit that I have had for a long time is rebooting my computer after handling sensitive information. My reason for doing this is to prevent attacks against my computer's memory.

An example of this would be if I unlocked my PGP key or SSH keys, or perhaps used my password manager. As soon as I am done using them, I would reboot in order to make sure that any residual data is cleared from memory.

I am aware that rebooting doesn't necessarily wipe the memory fully, it just feels better to do it (perceived security).

Is there really any point in doing this?

I'm using Ubuntu/GNOME Keyring.

Thanks

Comment: AS an aside: Memory != HDD

Comment: I am aware of this, I am talking about RAM, not HDD.

Comment: Ah. Good. The problem with the two is it's sometimes easy to confuse them. I have had several co workers who didn't.

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/86645/does-reboot-clear-ram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it doesn't. The value might still be stored even through reboot(the physical nature of RAM leads to this). While user level applications will not receive access to the memory(it will be zeroed out when allocated), any compromise that can read the **raw** RAM will still be able to find it.

**HOWEVER** this is the wrong question to ask. Really the problem is if you're compromised to that extent, it's not your system anymore. They could sit back, relax, and slowly siphon the information as you use it and you may never know. At that point rebooting or even shutting down and waiting for RAM to clear won't do anything. They already have it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What about programs that are not designed to be secure, such as grep? For example, if I am handling keys and I use grep to filter something out, would grep unload it from memory just as GnuPG would?

Comment: Once a thread in Linux is done, it's memory is freed(unless it's leaky... which grep isn't, and I'm pretty sure it doesn't write to disk either)

Comment: When memory is freed, is it zeroed out or is there some other process to destroy the data there?

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/86645/does-reboot-clear-ram

Comment: When allocated memory is freed it's not zeroed out, unless the app takes care about it.

Comment: So the recently unallocated memory could still be read from?

Comment: Only if they get full access to your system, but rebooting doesn't help either in that regard. Application level can't read it, only system level could read the raw memory

Comment: @JamieOnUbuntu I rewrote my answer. After reading it a few time I realized I went only in user space. This shorter answer should address it in a better manner.

Comment: @RobertMennell Thank you. I understand that once a system is compromised it should be nuked from orbit. I guess that my logic in this question is: "Now that I am done using my keys, I should reboot just in case I am compromised in 30 minutes. No need to have them in memory unnecessarily." Looks like I was right about it been just perceived security.

Comment: When you have a very confidential staff to do just consider having PC which is cut for the internet entirely. In our company we have a secured room.Otherwise just spend you efforts to protect PC rather than doing operations with assumptions that your PC is unsafe.